# What is the probability that if six balls are taken from a box that exactly four are red and at least one is green?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A box contains $3$ blue, $4$ red, $5$ green balls. Six balls are taken out at random and without replacement. What is the probability exactly four are red, at least one is green?

I noticed that it might be $4$R, $1$G and $1$ random or $4$R, $2$G, but I just can't solve it.

Comment: Hint: Use the hypergeometric distribution

Comment: i never learn it before, it wasn't in my textbooks.....i only use(4/12 *3/10 * 2/9 *1/8 *5/7*4/6) which is 4R2G and 4R1G1B to solve it, helppppppp.

Comment: That approach will not work as it assumes a particular order.

Comment: ahhhh i found the answer already, should be using the C thingy

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible cases: $$4R,2G \hspace{0.2cm} and \hspace{0.2cm} 4R,1G,1B$$
Total balls are $$4R,5G \hspace{0.2cm} and \hspace{0.2cm} 3B$$
For $4R,2G$: select balls in $$^4C_4 \cdot ^5C_2$$
For $4R,1G,1B$: select balls in $$^4C_4\cdot ^5C_1\cdot ^3C_1$$
Total ways to select 6 balls is $$^{4+5+3}C_6=^{12}C_6$$
Just divide:
$$P(4R,2G)=\frac{^4C_4\cdot ^5C_2}{^{12}C_6}$$
$$P(4R,1G,1B)=\frac{^4C_4\cdot ^5C_1\cdot ^3C_1}{^{12}C_6}$$

For 4R and at least 1G, add these two probabilities:
$$ \frac{^4C_4 \cdot ^5C_2+ ^4C_4 \cdot ^5C_1\cdot ^3C_1}{^{12}C_6}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are total (3b + 4r + 5g)=12 balls in the box.
Six balls are chosen.
The no of ways of picking exactly 4 red balls from the total 4 red balls is 4C4.
Similarly for at least 1 green ball, there are 5C1 + 5C2 + 5C3 + 5C4 + 5C5 ways.
But the total balls to picked is 6, so we consider 5C1 + 5C2 only

Now,4 red balls are compulsory, if we take 1 green ball, we can choose 1 blue ball.
This is possible in 3C1 ways.

if we take 2 green balls,there is no way to choose a blue ball.

So favourable outcomes: 4r1g1b and 4r2g = (4C4 * 5C1 * 3C1) + (4C4 * 5C2) ways